# C# - LINQ - Sum a field from other table

Tags: c#, .net, linq, group-by, sum

I need to join two tables (Movimientos and Cuentas), group by CuentasId and make a SUM of Movimientos.Monto
Movimientos has a CuentasId to join this, and I can get the data from Cuentas but can not get the Sum.

This is my best approach, any help will be preciated, I'm a little confused with the syntax. Thanks in advance and kind regards,

```
          var cuentas = (from mov in _data.Movimientos
                               join ct in _data.Cuentas
                               on mov.CuentasId equals ct.CuentasId
                               where ct.IsDeleted == 0 && mov.IsDeleted == 0
                               group ct by new
                               {
                                   CuentasId = ct.CuentasId,
                                   Alias = ct.Alias,
                                   Moneda = ct.Monedas.Nombre,
                                   Signo = ct.Monedas.Signo,
                                  Banco = ct.Bancos.Nombre
                               } into ctg
                               select new
                               {
                                   Alias = ctg.Key.Alias,
                                   Moneda = ctg.Key.Moneda,
                                   Signo = ctg.Key.Signo,
                                   Banco = ctg.Key.Banco,
                                   Monto = ctg.Sum(mov.Monto)
                               }
                                ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to group the value you want to sum like this

```
group mov.Monto by new { ..... } into ctg
```

Then `ctg` will be a collection of `mov.Monto` values grouped by your list of properties of `ct` and you'd just call `Sum` on `ctg` in your `select`

```
Monto = ctg.Sum()
```

So your new query would be

```
var cuentas = (from mov in _data.Movimientos
               join ct in _data.Cuentas
               on mov.CuentasId equals ct.CuentasId
               where ct.IsDeleted == 0 && mov.IsDeleted == 0
               group mov.Monto by new
               {
                   CuentasId = ct.CuentasId,
                   Alias = ct.Alias,
                   Moneda = ct.Monedas.Nombre,
                   Signo = ct.Monedas.Signo,
                   Banco = ct.Bancos.Nombre
               } into ctg
               select new
               {
                   Alias = ctg.Key.Alias,
                   Moneda = ctg.Key.Moneda,
                   Signo = ctg.Key.Signo,
                   Banco = ctg.Key.Banco,
                   Monto = ctg.Sum()
               }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks @juharr . This must be added or just replace the actual group?

Comment: @LeandroTupone Basically instead of `group ct` you do `group mov.Monto` then the `ctg` will be a collection of the grouped `Monto` values that you can just call `Sum` on.  Everything else would remain the same.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand the logic behind group by in LINQ

Answer (score 0):

You could also try grouping by first and then just summing the items later:

```
var cuentas = (from mov in _data.Movimientos.Where(w => w.IsDeleted == 0).GroupBy(g => g.CuentasId)
              join ct in _data.Cuentas.Where(w => w.IsDeleted == 0).GroupBy(g => new { CuentasId = g.CuentasId, Alias = g.Alias, Monedas = g.Monedas.Nombre, Signo = g.Monedas.Signo, Banco = g.Bancos.Nombre })
              on mov.Key.CuentasId equals ct.Key.CuentasId
              select new
              {
                  Alias = ct.Key.Alias,
                  Moneda = ct.Key.Moneda,
                  Signo = ct.Key.Signo,
                  Banco = ct.Key.Banco,
                  Monto = mov.Sum(s => s.Monto)
               }
               ).ToList();
```